# PHP imap_open() => [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] for imap.gmail.com

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, gmail, imap

It's already several days that we have started experience issues with `imap_open` function when try to connect to `imap.gmail.com` it returns:

```
Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

Here is the sample of the code that I try to run:

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", username, password, NULL, 1);
```

Can this be an issue with the versions of PHP/Open SSL? If yes how can I solve it?

Comment: Did this code work originally? Are you sure the credentials are correct?

Answer (score 9):

There are two possible reasons:

1-Credentials are incorrect.

2-Gmail do not authorize imap for unrecognized web apps, you should enable this fact here [gmail enable less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: Kassav' the login credentials are correct, also we have tried to do same action form another servers. For some of them it works well, for some of them it doesn't work.

Comment: Our emails are app emails, they are not ending with gmail.com and it's impossible to make the call without SSL. Google has deprecated non-SSL calls for app emails.